# Bluestacks on Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, wine, fedora-15, bluestacks

I am trying to use Bluestacks for running Android application on my Linux Fedora using Wine.

I tried `wine BlueStacks-SplitInstaller_native.exe` from terminal. It gave  me `Install Mono for Windows to run .NET 2.0 ...` error, so i downloaded Mono For Windows from [here](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html).

I installed the complete package [checked all boxes including GTK etc] it using

`wine mono-2.10.9-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe` After the installation is done. After a while it just seemed to stop executing commands. However it did not return the prompt on terminal even after waiting for a long time,so i did Ctrl-C to get back the prompt. This showed some fixeme for the console.

Following this by,

`wine BlueStacks-SplitInstaller_native.exe` The bluestacks installer comes up and immediately gives the error dialog stating

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x7de321a8 in 32-bit code (0x100035cf).
Register dump:
 CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
 EIP:100035cf ESP:0033f57c EBP:0033f5a0 EFLAGS:00010246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:0012bd98 EBX:0033fa54 ECX:7de32160 EDX:0033f594
 ESI:00000643 EDI:0033f84c
Stack dump:
0x0033f57c:  0012bd98 0033f594 0033f84c 00000643
0x0033f58c:  0033fa54 00000136 00000000 00000000
0x0033f59c:  84ac8254 0033f64c 10005604 00000002
0x0033f5ac:  0012bd98 1001854a 0033f84c 0033fa54
0x0033f5bc:  0033f5d0 002206ec 00000000 00220706
0x0033f5cc:  00220706 7bc3d409 00000643 0012bd98
```

and lot other details.

The installer meanwhile continues upto 98% installation and hangs.

What step did i do wrong?

**Note:** I don't want a VM for this purpose (I am not going to do anything on Windows except use Whatsapp). Any other alternatives are welcome. I have tried with [Youwave](https://superuser.com/questions/580320/youwave-on-wine-fedora) too, but with little success.

Comment: are you running x86 fedora or x64?

Comment: 32 bit 
`Linux 2.6.43.8-1.fc15.i686`